# Quran 67:3-4; What is meant by "Again turn thy vision a second time: (thy) vision will come back to thee dull and discomfited, in a state worn out."

Tags: quran, tafseer

From [this transliteration](http://transliteration.org/quran/WebSite_CD/MixYuwsuf/Fram2E.htm) and Yusuf Ali's English translation:

067.003
Al-Ladhī Khalaqa Sab`a Samāwātin Ţibāqāan ۖ Mā Tará Fī Khalqi Ar-Raĥmāni Min Tafāwutin ۖ Fārji`i Al-Başara Hal Tará Min Fuţūrin

He Who created the seven heavens one above another: No want of proportion wilt thou see in the Creation of (God) Most Gracious. ***So turn thy vision again: seest thou any flaw?***

‍الَّذِي خَ‍‍لَ‍‍قَ سَ‍‍بْ‍‍عَ سَمَا‌و‍َ‍‌ات‌‍ٍ‌ طِ‍‍بَاق‍‍ا‌ ً‌ ۖ مَا‌ تَ‍رَ‌ى‌ فِي خَ‍‍لْ‍‍قِ ‌ال‍‍رَّحْمَنِ مِ‍‌‍نْ تَفَا‌وُت‌‍ٍ‌ ۖ فَا‌رْجِعِ ‌الْبَ‍‍صَ‍‍رَ‌ هَلْ تَ‍رَ‌ى‌ مِ‍‌‍نْ فُ‍‍طُ‍‍و‌رٍ

067.004
Thumma Arji`i Al-Başara Karratayni Yanqalib 'Ilayka Al-Başaru Khāsi'āan Wa Huwa Ĥasīrun

***Again turn thy vision a second time: (thy) vision will come back to the dull and discomfited, in a state worn out.***

ثُ‍‍مَّ ‌ا‌رْجِعِ ‌الْبَ‍‍صَ‍‍رَ‌ كَ‍رَّتَ‍‍يْ‍‍نِ يَ‍‌‍ن‍‍‍قَ‍‍لِ‍‍بْ ‌إِلَ‍‍يْ‍‍كَ ‌الْبَ‍‍صَ‍‍رُ‌ خَ‍‍اسِئا‌ ً‌ ‌وَهُوَ‌ حَسِيرٌ

I am sorry, this does not make sense.  An explanation of the context in which these ayas were revealed would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tafseer according to Imam Qatadah, Imam Ibn Abbas:

> *And [he] who created seven heavens in layers. You do not see in the creation of the Most Merciful any inconsistency. So look again [to the sky]; do you see any breaks? Then look twice again. [Your] vision will return to you humbled*

(meaning that your vision will always fail to find an inconsistency no matter how you look more).

As translated from Arabic [Tafseer](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura67-aya4.html).

Comment: Can you edit and give a link or a reference for your quote?

Comment: I know this is surat al-Mulk, I can't see your reference in there. As ibn 'Abbas commented it as it seems.